# passing data using delegates between viewcontrollers without any navigation controller connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

There are many examples of passing data between two view controllers, where one view controller navigates to another view controller.

But is it possible to pass data using custom protocols & delegates between view controllers that are not connected by navigation controller?

So, an example could be: Three view controllers namely are, `A`,`B`,`C`. `A` navigates to `B`, and `B`navigates to `C`. I know how to pass data between `A` & `B` using custom protocols & delegates. But can we pass data between `C` & `A`. Thus `A` can be `C`'s delegate and thereby can receive data from `C`. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is use **delegates** for backward passing of data

Refer [simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) link for passing data from C to A controller.

Check [basic-delegate-example](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/basic-delegate-example/) link.

Another way is by **posting notification.** for backward passing of data

Check [Comunicate-Two-Views](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/017-Comunicate-Two-Views.pl) link.

Comment: Thanx for your early reply. But in the first example, the two view controllers are connected using modal view. Same goes for the second example.

Comment: yeah notifications can be used, but i wanted to know whether it can be achieved using custom protocols & delegates.

Comment: the second example wont work, because they do not inherit the custom protocol.
Hey I know how to pass data using delegates between two view controllers that are connected using navigation controller.

Comment: i m talking about backward messaging (passing of data)

Comment: yeah backward messaging itself. So A navigates to B. Using delegates B can pass to A. But i wanted to know between C and A.

Comment: use post notification to pass data

Comment: yes prince that is one way, also i could use singleton. But it still remains open as to whether it can be done using protocols or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some singleton class and implement delegate protocol in it. So you will have opportunity to pass data between any view controllers.

Comment: could u elucidate a bit on that.

Comment: OK. Singleton is a desisn pattern that have only one instance and you can always call it from anywhere in your code. So in your scheme A, B and C view controllers appear one more class D, which can have access to any controller, even without connection with navigationController

Comment: This are examples of singletons

NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNotificationCenter* notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
UIApplication* myApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

Comment: yeah using singleton and utility class we can achieve that. Similarly we can use notifications, but these are alternatives. Cant we pass using delegates and protocols?

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean by delegates and protocols?

Comment: u can see @Prince's first link for that. There you can a connection between the two views which are passing each other data. I want an example where data is passed between controllers not being connected. I hope i made sense with that.

Answer (score 0):

For Send data from second view controller to First Controller use following github project:-

https://github.com/mauli787/CustomDelegateDataPassing