# can i use to pass a data with 'navigation controller back button' in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue

i have 2 view controller and a navigation controller . 
we shall say main for 1 and detail for 2. 
when i push button in main, detail opens and main opens with back button

well, i want to change a label text or a string in main view controller when i clicked a button and back button on detail view controller.

how can i make this?

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"deneme"])
{
MainViewController *main=[segue destinationViewController];
main.detay=@"denme";

}
```

i tried prepareForSegue and function that i wrote but i couldn't.

Comment: Do you want to perform an action in mainViewController when you click on the back button in detailViewController or when you click another button in detailViewController?

Comment: why dont you use a delegate for passing back a value , in this case its best solution.

Comment: MainViewController *mn=[[MainViewController alloc]init];
mn.detay=@"gönder";

i tried another button but didnt work. @user1966109

Comment: And i dont know to use delegate, how can i use @pawan

Comment: @kordiseps check my answer, i have tried to send you all helpful link as much i found. and written a demo code for you to understand it. good luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"koediseps"

i have written a demo for passing data for you, download it and check it. 
if you found any problem , ask me.

here is the  [link for data passing with delegate demo](https://github.com/pawankmrai/DelegateTesting)

some other useful link [simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/)

[passing-data-using-delegates-between-viewcontrollers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757309/passing-data-using-delegates-between-viewcontrollers-without-any-navigation-cont)