# How to save data to NSMutableDictionary and load data from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to create shopping cart. I want to put all data `NSMutableDictionary` from `NSDictionary` with Bar-code number which has **DataItem** variable as `key`. I have created `NSMutableDictionary` with that code block;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    DataItem = [[[_response objectForKey:@"Data"] objectForKey:@"Items"] objectForKey:@"Item"];

    NSMutableDictionary *CartItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for(NSDictionary *transaction in DataItem)

    {
       [CartItems setValue:transaction  forKey:[transaction objectForKey:@"BarcodeNumber"]];
    }
}
```

When I push another `viewController` for selection another item to put cart. Once again,push that `viewController`, it deletes before item from **CartItems** variable.

I know I have putted that code block `NSMutableDictionary *CartItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];` inside of **viewDidLoad**. That's why, It generates new **CartItems** variable. If I want to put it **.h** file, it returns **nil**. I did not find any solution.

Is there any way to load data to `NSMutableDictionary` for reusing? or Is there another way to create same logic? Thanks.

Comment: is DataItem nil ? Also please follow naming conventions , Class names start with upper case letters and variables start with lowerCase letters.

Comment: You can use a singleton, as the two answers state, or you can pass references to the dictionary to each view controller as you go along. There are lots of answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a singleton class for data which returns same object with first time initialization and use that for storing your data.

```
+ (id)getBE {
    static MyBEClass *objMyBEClass = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        objMyBEClass = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return objMyBEClass;
}
```

Make CarItems dictionary a property of BE class so you can get this from your view controller.

```
@property(strong)NSMutableDictionary *CartItems;
```

In init method of BE class initialize your array/dictionary.

```
CartItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

Comment: pls follow the naming conventions!

Comment: Actually I used same names which asker user so he would not get confused.

Answer (score 0):

use a singleton class to store you data like [this](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by using `NSUserDefaults`. Here is viewDidLoad-

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

        DataItem = [[[_response objectForKey:@"Data"] objectForKey:@"Items"] objectForKey:@"Item"];

        NSUserDefaults *prefrence=[[NSUserDefaults alloc]init];

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"cartItems"]!=nil) {

            NSMutableDictionary *CartItems=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"cartItems"];

            for(NSDictionary *transaction in DataItem)
            {

                [CartItems setValue:transaction  forKey:[transaction objectForKey:@"BarcodeNumber"]];

            }

            [prefrence setObject:CartItems forKey:@"cartItems"];

        }else{

            NSMutableDictionary *CartItems = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

            for(NSDictionary *transaction in DataItem)
            {

                [CartItems setValue:transaction  forKey:[transaction objectForKey:@"BarcodeNumber"]];

            }
                [prefrence setObject:CartItems forKey:@"cartItems"];
        }

    }
```

whenever you want to clear your cart that time also clear `NSUserDefaults` using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"cartItems"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to use a Singleton for such a thing except if your building a huge app with many controllers, and you need your chart everywhere.

If it's not the case, I would suggest you to pass the char as parameter from one controller to the other one, and pass it back with a delegate as in this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757309/passing-data-using-delegates-between-viewcontrollers-without-any-navigation-cont).

if you have an application built with a single navigation controller, remember that it is not deallocated, so you can save data there. Just make getters and setters of your variable visible (.h file) or the variable itself, but remember that that is not a very good practise because it looks like it will be modified by many controllers, and thats another reason why you should avoid using singletons.

Hope it helps!